# location.reload() in jquery .post callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload, jquery-callback

I have some questions regarding the execution order inside the callback function of `jquery.post`. For example, I have the following code:

```
$.post("ajax/test.html", function(newData){
    location.reload();
    $(".result").html(newData);
});
```

I expect the text in `".result"` is changed into `newData`. However, it isn't. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to reload the page?

Comment: But you are reloading the page before it get to that line.

Comment: When you call a address your script is halted. So when `location.reload();` is called, the script is halted. Try removing that.

Comment: put comments `//` before `location.reload();`

Comment: Imagine you shout "Hey Deer! Move out of the way" before shooting it. Doesn't make any sense right ? You call location.reload(), telling browser to scrap the current state of the page including data and script. And your next instruction calls on changing something one the page.

Comment: Think about it this way:  Reloading the page reloads *everything* at that url -- including the javascript.